# An issue occurred evaluating project ':react-native-camera'

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I used react-native-camera in my project and got this error:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-camera'.

> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might need to update your buildToolsVersion. You can check https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1490.

Comment: @AMITKUMARKARN It already is 26.0.2